# Python: drop index from tensor

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, tensor, indices

I have two tensors.

tensor_A corresponds to a batch of 8 images, with 20 classes of objects and each image is 256 x 256

tensor_B corresponds to 8 arrays of len 20 full of 1 or 0, corresponding to if the object class is present

tensor_A.shape = ([8, 20, 256, 256])

tensor_B.shape = ([8, 20])

from tensor_A, I want to drop indices that correspond to 1 in tensor_B

for example if tensor_B[0] = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

I would like to do tensor_A[0, 0, :, :].drop then tensor_A[0, 2, :, :].drop and so on, but all in one step

So far i have identified the indices that correspond to 1, by using the following:

```
for i in range(8):
    (tensor_B[i, :] == 0).nonzero())
# code for dropping here
```

Not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

What you want won't work because:

```
# A -> tensor of shape (8, 20, 256, 256)
# B -> tensor of shape (8, 20)

# If B[0] = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
dropped_A_0 = A[0, B[0] == 0, :, :]
# dropped_A_0 -> tensor of shape (1, 13, 256, 256)

# If B[1] = [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
dropped_A_1 = A[1, B[1] == 0, :, :]
# dropped_A_1 -> tensor of shape (1, 16, 256, 256)
```

You see the problem? When you "drop" values from the rows of A, they aren't the same shape any more, and thus cannot exist together as a single tensor. What you can have is a list of the rows of A with dropped values:

```
dropped_A = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    dropped_A.append(A[i, B[i] == 0, :, :])
```

Another thing you can do is simply set the unneeded values in A to 0.

```
A[B == 1] = 0
```